# Spss loop and testing for normal distribution

Tags: loops, testing, spss, normal-distribution

I am currently working in SPSS. I want to creat 50 groups and for each group i  generate 100 random numbers. After this i want to test each group for normal distribution. Unfortunately, this doesnt work.

Thats my code:

```
input program.
   loop l=1 to 50 by 1.
     loop index_2=1 to 100 by 1.
     COMPUTE index_1 =l. 
     end case.
   end loop.
end loop.
end file.
end input program.
exe.
```

and i know how to test for normal distribution, but i dont know how to select a group.

```
  EXAMINE VARIABLES=Zufall_1 
  /PLOT BOXPLOT STEMLEAF NPPLOT 
  /COMPARE GROUPS 
  /STATISTICS DESCRIPTIVES 
  /CINTERVAL 95 
  /MISSING LISTWISE 
  /NOTOTAL.
```

Can someone help me pls :)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create group variable properly**

Things are pretty easy if the group variable (index_1) is set for each case (line). This is the way to do:

```
INPUT PROGRAM.
   LOOP #i = 1 TO 50 BY 1.
     LOOP #j = 1 TO 100 BY 1.
         COMPUTE index_1 = #i.
         COMPUTE index_2 = #j.
         COMPUTE zufall_1 = RV.NORMAL(0,1). /* random number, normal dist.
     END CASE.
   END LOOP.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
EXECUTE.
```

The variables beginning with '#' are so called scratch variables. They are not stored in the dataset.

**2. Run a procedure for each group**

Simply use the `SPLIT FILE` command before the procedure.

```
SPLIT FILE SEPARATE BY index_1.
<procedure command(s)>
SPLIT FILE OFF.
```